# Database relationship between employee and timesheet

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a system whereby it allows employees to log in day they work (eg, Monday/Tuesday...etc) and their time.

I have the "Employee" tables and a "Timesheet" table. Should the relationship be one to one or many to many or others?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It depends on the definition of timesheet. What does a single entry in this table represent?

Comment: @Andrei The timesheet allows the employees to select the day, location, and time they work. if that is what you are asking....

Comment: if each row in the timesheet only describes the time worked by a single employee then I would assume you need a 1-many relationship (with the employee on the 1 side and the timesheet on the many side). That way each employee can record many timesheets and each timesheet entry can be matched to the specific employee.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the answer! that helped!